# Flex item to occupy space of sibling item when removed

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

Say, I have a layout of three columns in a full-width & full-height wrapper like this:

```
<div class = "wrap">
    <div class="col1">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="other-stuff">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, `col2` can be hidden or show, with a jquery animate that either slides it in from the left edge of the browser, or out the left edge. `col1` is always present, so is `other-stuff`.

Both `col1` and `col2`, when present are 264px wide and 100% height.

What I'd need is for `other-stuff` take up the remaining of horizontal screen space, and shrink if `col2` is present, and grow when `col2` is animated back out of the page. How should I tackle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the [**`flex-grow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property, which tells a flex item to occupy any free remaining space.

So for instance you would say:

```
.other-stuff { flex-grow: 1; }
```

This would tell the item to stretch horizontally as much as possible (assuming `flex-direction: row`).

If `.col-2` were missing it would stretch the full width of the container until it hits `.col-1`.

If `.col-2` were present it would stretch until it his `.col-2`.

For an illustration see this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/6gzt75sL/11/).

Comment: What if `.col-1` has a fixed position, and therefore `.other-stuff` needs to be 246px from the left edge when `.col-2`is not present? And when `.col-2` is present, then 528px.

Comment: Got that fixed.. The snapping of the width change is a bit annoying, but I can live with that, unless you can say how that can be made into a smoother motion, tried transitions for all and flex-grow - didn't work. Accepting as OQ answered and works ok.