# How can I slide the sidebar out of view and make the content flexbox resize to fill the void?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

My flexbox layout is based on [Philip Walton's Holy Grail Layout](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/).

I'm trying to create a slide in/slide out navigation sidebar much like [these](http://callmenick.com/post/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions) but using flexbox layout, not absolute positioned divs.

I've seen many flexbox sliding menus such as this [Off Canvas Flexbox Menu](http://codepen.io/oknoblich/pen/klnjw), but they all seem to slide the article over the sidebar. I want the sidebar to push/pull the article when sliding in and out of view.

To achieve this I have been toggling the CSS display property between `display:block` and `display:none`. This works perfectly as the sidebar is hidden and the content is resized automatically to fill the new larger space. [JSFiddle demonstrating display toggle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zhzuwwp/4/).

However, when I try to use the translate properties such as `transform:translateX(-12em)` to slide the sidebar out of view the content remains in the same place and does not resize.  This leaves a hole where the parent container can be seen. [JSFiddle demonstrating the sliding toggle](https://jsfiddle.net/kp415wzc/4/).

**Question:** How can I slide the `nav` out of view and make the `article` resize to fill the void?

Note: I would like to achieve this without using javascript.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34909809/3597276

Comment: Thanks Michael. The related question is about `flex-grow` so I'm not sure it's quite what I'm looking for.  Or if it is, I can't see how it would work in this scenario.

Comment: The `flex-grow` property provides a method for making the content of a flex container re-size to fill a void. As that seems to be a primary component of your question, I posted the related link.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Transforms are purely visual--they don't actually move the element from its layout location.

Use `margin-left` instead.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vu47afeq/2/)

```css
html,
body,
main,
article,
nav,
aside {
  height: 97%;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 1.5%;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
article {
  flex: 1;
}
nav,
aside {
  /* 12em is the width of the sidebars */
  flex: 0 0 12em;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease
}
/* Checkbox hack to toggle nav visibility */

input ~ nav {
  margin-left: -12em;
}
input:checked ~ nav {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<header style="background-color: #a4c400;color:#fff;padding:0.25em">
  <label for="toggle">Click to Toggle Nav</label>
</header>
<main style="background-color: #ccc;">
  <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" checked style="display:none" />
  <nav style="background-color: #8dd0f2;">Nav</nav>
  <article style="background-color:#fff">Article</article>
  <aside style="background-color: #8dd0f2;">Aside</aside>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be another way.

```css
html,
body,
main,
article,
nav,
aside {
  height: 97%;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 1.5%;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}
nav,
aside {
  /* 12em is the width of the sidebars */
  flex: 0 0 12em;
  transition: all 0.3s ease
}
/* Checkbox hack to toggle nav visibility */

input:checked ~ nav {
  transform: translateX(0);
  flex: 1;
}
input ~ nav {
  transform: translateX(-12em);
  flex: 0;
  width: 0px;
}
input:checked ~ article {
  flex: 2;
}
input ~ article {
  flex: 3;
}
```

```html
<header style="background-color: #a4c400;color:#fff;padding:0.25em">
  <label for="toggle">Click to Toggle Nav</label>
</header>
<main style="background-color: #ccc;">
  <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" checked style="display:none" />
  <nav style="background-color: #8dd0f2;">Nav</nav>
  <article style="background-color:#fff">Article</article>
  <aside style="background-color: #8dd0f2;">Aside</aside>
</main>
```